# How to assign role while registration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I'm working in laravel and using spatie laravel-permission. So i want to assign some role while registration and user can choose it via radio-button. I've tried some solutions from similar topic [Assigning the role while user registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617190/assigning-the-role-while-user-registration)
But it return an error. Code and error text you can find down. Sorry for stupid question and grammar mistakies-i'm newbie in programminпg and english isn't my native language.

RegisterController (other code is default)

```
protected function create(array $data, Request $request )
{
    return $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'patro' => $data['patro'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                ]);
    $user->assignRole($request->input('role'));return $user;
}
```

register.blade.php
(other code is default)

```
<select>
<option name="role">Teacher</option>
<option name="role">Student</option></select>
```

error

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 1 passed in C:\OpenServer\domains\uni\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RegistersUsers.php on line 34 and exactly 2 expected
```

Comment: Show how you're using the `create` function. If it's coming from a route, the Request injection should be first.

Comment: It's default auth RegisterController in laravel, i've just add 'patro' and 'surname'. Just tried to replace Request injection-no changes

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `$data` is the request inputs and the router is not calling `create` so you can't just add parameters to that method unless you want to also adjust the `register` method where `create` is called to then pass that extra argument you are adding

Answer (score 0):

Any statement after a return statement does not get executed

Remove the return statement in the create method before the statement to assign role and shift it to the end if you really want the return value to be the newly created user.

The error you are getting is because of `event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));` in the register function of the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait.

Passing $request to the create method is not required because request data is already being passed as `array $data` so `$data['role']` will be same as `$request->input('role')`

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'patro' => $data['patro'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                ]);

    //$user->assignRole($request->input('role'));
    $user->assignRole($data['role']);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer, there is no RegistersUsers in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth, so i found it at laravel/ui/auth-backend. I copied register method, changed it. And there is no errors after registration, but role dont assigns to registrated user. And second advice with request() didnt help.

Comment: Did you remove the return statement  from `return $user = User::create()`? because if you don't remove then any code after that won't be executed

Comment: i find similar problem, but there is no solution too https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1008

Comment: What value does `$request->role` have you can `dd($request->role)` as the first statement in the create method and see

Comment: oh, sorry, i've added before name, and get result "null"

Comment: You `<option name="role">Teacher</option>` tags seems to be missing `value="teacher"` hence you might be getting $request->role as null. Try rectifying the option tags and let me know if everything works as expected

Comment: After adding value to the options tag do you get $request->role as desired value and not null? And you are getting the role received as $request->role assigned to the user?

Comment: nothing after adding value. It still null. The role didn't assigned.

Comment: After adding value to options what do you get with `dd($request->role)` as the first line in the method null or some value?

Comment: Am sorry just noticed the name attribute should be on select tag not the options tag. Ensure that the name attribute is on select tag and option tags have value. Then check with `dd($request->role)` as first line on the controller method and see what value you get

Comment: okay, it return 'teacher', but in "model_has_roles" table no new records

Comment: Try  assigning 'teacher` role to a user via tinker and see if the functionality of assignRole works properly

Comment: yeah, i've just login with test user and try auth()->user()->assignRole('teacher') in HomeController-it works, new record in "models_has_roles"

Comment: sorry, but you have no more ideas?

Comment: Yeah. it's finally works, i don't know how, but it works, and it returns another error)
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in C:\OpenServer\domains\uni\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php on line 101
but registration and assign is good

Comment: Pls include the code for RegisterController method where this error occurs line 101 as per the error

Comment: public function register(Request $request)

    {

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all(), $request)));

        $this->guard()->login($user); //line 101

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
            : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }}

Comment: $this->guard()->login($user); -101 line

Comment: Copy the create method from the answer and replace the create method in your RegisterController with it. Also change the the register method in the RegistersUsers with `event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())))` then let me know if you still get the error

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Models\User::assignRole()